# php can't find solution, need to resolve this php prob

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, solution

I have this code

```
<html>
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Desarrollo Web</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$jugadors_de_lacrosse = array( "Billy Bitter", "Chris Bocklet", "Jeremy Boltus" );
$jugadors_de_pilota_basca = array( "Iñaqui" );
$esports = array();
$esports["Lacrosse"] = $jugadors_de_lacrosse;
$esports["Pilota Basca"] = $jugadors_de_pilota_basca;

foreach( $esports as $esport => $jugadors ) {
    echo "my favorite players of $esport are ";
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

now I want to print out the names of players after my favorites players of $esport are"here names of player" I have to do with another foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
echo "my favorite players of $esport are ". implode(',',$jugadors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
echo "My favourite players are ";
foreach($esports as $jugadors) {
  echo $jugadors;
}
```